Is there any way I can get more detailed failure information from Time Machine? Are there logs?
I swap in multiple Time Machine backup drives on my main desktop to have redundant backups. At least I try to. However, lately backups to one of my disks seems to always fail, possibly because Time Machine only tries to backup to the other.
However, I'm not sure as the only error I get from the main UI is "Backup Failed". No indication of whether any files were backed up, which files weren't backed up, or why.
Is there any way I can get more detailed failure information from Time Machine so I can see what's going wrong so I can fix it?

Plug the suspect drive in, option-click the TM icon, ask it to verify the backup.

There are so so many variables and the one constant, is looking at steps for the wrong version of macOS or the wrong destination format or a destination that is network as opposed to directly connected makes for a lot of wrong paths down which you could travel.
I would honestly start with an online chat with Apple Support and then asking a follow on question with some details on exactly how you set up Time Machine and what version of macOS has the problem.
If you wanted to dive into the logs, this is where I would start:

https://eclecticlight.co/2024/01/10/time-machine-in-sonoma-detection-and-diagnosis-with-t2m2/

Use the free tool T2M2 to assist in checks.
